# React Native - How to run an App without the development server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Okay, my boss is asking me for some progress. And I have a pretty stable version of the app, but you need to have the development server for the app to run.

The app is **NOT** going to the google store yet. How can I get an .Apk that runs without the development server?

Because all I find is docs about signing keys and deploying to the Google App Store. But I don't want that yet. All I want is to get an .Apk that I can give to my boss and that he can run and test the App without any problems.

How can I do this? 
Oh, and I'm on windows.

Comment: you can make unsigned/signed apk and install it in any device.

Comment: Go through this 
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/signed-apk-android.html
for signed apk else directly use from your app
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
and you can find your apk in android/app/build/outputs/apk

Comment: @RaviRupareliya - Will Debug APK not run on another network?

Answer (score 0):

there is a pretty good option and it is to use APP Center Visual Studio, the only thing that a signature asks you (that you can generate it from your machine), at the end of the process it gives you an APK in a link for you to download it.

https://appcenter.ms/apps